# Blade laravel not working in ftp-simple, what's the solution?

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, laravel-8, ftp-client

I have a problem when I use Laravel 7 and upload code in Cpanel.

I want to add a page using the "ftp-simple" extension, for editing and adding, but the blade function doesn't work.

The result is that the header, footer, and CSS do not carry over into the new page.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufo7c.png)
old page, blade detected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK6SU.png)
new page, blade not detected

Comment: Looks like your blade file is being accessed directly instead of through Laravel's methods. How are you accessing it, and what does ftp-simple have to do with it?

Comment: Is your view file named correctly? Make sure it has the `.blade.php` extension and not `.php`

Comment: Please show us the function that generates this page.

Comment: Because, as already mentioned, your file is named `gearbox-repair.php`, not `gearbox-repair.blade.php`. Only `.blade.php` files get parsed by Blade

Comment: thanks, I forgot to add .blade.php